# Reading Japanese file names with JS in VS Code

Tags: javascript, file, character-encoding

I'm working on MacOS 12 and VS Code. When I select a file with a Japanese file name and output it to the console:

```
File.openDialog();
$.writeln(file.name);
```

the Japanese characters are lost and I get gibberish (a mix of number/characters/percentage symbols). I have added Japanese as a preferred language in Mac OS, switched to Japanese as keyboard output, changed the language of VS Code to Japanese, changed in the Settings of VS Code "Files:Encoding" from UTF-8 to Shift JIS, but nothing helped.

Could someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Numbers, characters and percent?  seems the filename is URL Encoded or percent encoded.

Comment: That's probably true, since VC Code doesn't recognise Japanese characters. The actual file name is in Japanese, though.

Comment: So, @fnostro thanks to your comment, I have researched more about URL encoding and found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript which perfectly help. I'll update my post accordingly - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Even simpler, using `file.fsName` gives back Japanese characters. How could I have missed that…

---

This post holds the answer:
[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

You can encode/decode the 'gibberish' with decodeURIComponent(str) and decodeURIComponent(str) respectively and in my case, it worked perfectly.

(Thanks @fnostro for the comment which helped me research in the right direction.)